# Haskell - mapping over a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I've been trying to get a list of lists from a list of lists of ints for example:

`[[0,0,1,4,7,10,11,12,16],[1,4,4,6,7,7,12,12,19],[0,0,0,2,4,7,11,12,13]]`

should yield `[[0,1,0],[0,4,0],[1,4,0]`..and so on`]`

I can get `[0,1,0]` using

```
map head saidList
```

And so I've been trying then to use that on the tail of the lists but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be hugely appreciated because this is the final and very small part of a huge project.

Comment: I like the name `saidList` :)

Answer (score 9):

Look into `Data.List`

```
ghci> :t Data.List.transpose
Data.List.transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
ghci> Data.List.transpose [[0,0,1,4,7,10,11,12,16],[1,4,4,6,7,7,12,12,19],[0,0,0,2,4,7,11,12,13]]
[[0,1,0],[0,4,0],[1,4,0],[4,6,2],[7,7,4],[10,7,7],[11,12,11],[12,12,12],[16,19,13]]
```

Comment: Oh transpose is exactly what I need!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your approach

```
map head l
```

only produces the first list and only works if all lists in the original list of lists are not empty.

You need a way to discard empty lists (you do not want to take the head of these), and then a way to apply the same procedure to the tails of the non-null lists. Here is a possible solution:

```
filterNonNull x = filter (\y -> not (null y)) x

f x = if null h then [] else h : t
    where
      n = filterNonNull x
      h = (map head n)
      t = f (map tail n)
```

I tested it on ghci:

```
f [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7,8]]
```

gives

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6]]
```